# how to delete rows from a column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I have a column named "Nomor #" and rows "Total Nomor #" in that column which I want to delete. but it still throws an error message. And have this code:

```
data = myretaildata[myretaildata['Nomor #']==['Total Nomor #'].index
myretaildata.drop(data.index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Not a lot of details here. Maybe some examples will help you. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Comment: I don't understand, do you have a column named `Nomor #` but I don't get the `Total Nomor #`. Is it a calculation I guess? What's the error?

Comment: Could you please post the error message you are receiving in your question

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to filter out the values of "Total Nomor #" contained within the column "Nomor #" then:

myretaildata[myretaildata["Nomor #"] != "Total Nomor #"]